# How to construct and Perform a transaction on Tezos blockchain

Tags: javascript, blockchain, rpc, tezos

I'm trying to construct, sign and broadcast a transaction on the tezos blockchain.

Here is my current code

```
const rpcUrl = "someTestnetRPC";

//generate private key
// get information about the most recent block
//reveal status    
//reveal operation
//can't quite figure out how to make this reveal transaction, this is the data 
  data: {
      branch: mostRecentBlock,
      contents: [
        {
          kind: "reveal",
          fee: "1",
          public_key: TezBridgeCrypto.crypto
            .getKeyFromSeed(random_seed)
            .getPublicKey(),
          gas_limit: "10500",
          storage_limit: "0",
        },
      ],
    }
   
 //I don't know the url to send this request to. 
  let binaryFromRpc = await axios({
    method: "post",
    url: `${rpcUrl}/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/forge/operations`,
    data: {
      branch: mostRecentBlock,
      contents: [
        {
          kind: "transaction",
          source: sourceAddr,
          fee: "1",
          counter: (Number(counter.data) + 1).toString(),
          gas_limit: "10500",
          storage_limit: "0",
          amount: "1",
          destination: "tz1biFoRp3n9X2r4o3sgcqRLkXAXce7hpPLp",
        },
      ],
    },
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
    },
  });

  const signature = Buffer.from(
    ed25519.Sign(
      Buffer.from(await blake2b(`0x03${binaryFromRpc.data}`, 256), "utf-8"),
      Buffer.from(random_seed, "utf-8")
    )
  ).toString("hex");

  const injectionData = `${binaryFromRpc.data}${signature}`;

    await axios({
      method: "post",
      url: `${rpcUrl}/injection/operation?chain=test&async`,
      data: injectionData,
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
    });
```

When I send this request the final injection goes through, no failure message, no content in the returned data and I can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `async` and `chain` flags from the injection query you should either receive operation hash (that indicates you operation is now in the mempool with `applied` status) or a prevalidation error.

Async flag can be used to submit operations that are temporarily invalid (e.g. issues with counter or insufficient balance) but can be resolved when other operations are applied.

Test chain is no longer used in Tezos, you should default to `main` instead. At some point test chain was spawned in parallel to the main one at a certain governance period to test the protocol upgrade.

Generally, unless you need a very granular access to the state I would recommend using [Taquito library](https://tezostaquito.io/) to interact with the Tezos blockchain.